# Disallow Skype from showing icons next to phone numbers

Tags: skype

Is it possible to programme a website so that it disallows Skype from adding it's icons next to phone numbers?

Thanks, Steph

Comment: Initally this seems completely unrelated, but I get what you mean. I think. 

But why would you not want them to? It's up to the client to decide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this in the page head:

```
<meta name="SKYPE_TOOLBAR" content="SKYPE_TOOLBAR_PARSER_COMPATIBLE" />
```

Details on the [skype forum](http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=78380)